# GoogleMap.MarkerClick event fired more than one time

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android, and I have different Marker in the map, I'd like that when I select one of these Marker the camera moves to the Marker and it opens the InfoWindow, now when I click the marker a lot of event are fired, like six, the map moves to the marker , it opens the infowindow but it closes it right away. This is the code I'm using:

```
            _map.Clear ();
            var infoWindow = new InformationWindow ();
            _map.SetInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindow);
            _map.MarkerClick += HandleMarkerClick;
.
.
void HandleMarkerClick (object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("CLICK MArker"+e.Marker.Id);
        }
```

The same happens with the InfoWindowClick, by the way for now I'm just trying to figure out why this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the `markerClickEventArgs.Handled` to be `true`?

The sample code for `Marker Click Events`as following:

```
private void MapOnMarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs markerClickEventArgs)
{
    markerClickEventArgs.Handled = true;
    Marker marker = markerClickEventArgs.P0;
    if (marker.Id.Equals(MyMarkerId)) // The ID of a specific marker the user clicked on.
    {
        _map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(new LatLng(20.72110, -156.44776), 13));
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, String.Format("You clicked on Marker ID {0}", marker.Id), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/#2.3.1.marker-click-events).

Comment: Setting Handled to be true doesn't resolve the problem. By the way MyMarkerId how should be setted?